# Func<T, U, double> et al. as a Parameters in Constructor

Tags: c#

I have the following extract from a relatively complex piece of code I am following

```
IDictionary<string, double> startingProbabilitiesDict = GetNewIDictionaryStringDouble();
IDictionary<string, double> transitionProbabilitiesDict = GetNewIDictionaryStringDouble();
IDictionary<string, double> emissionProbabilitiesDict = GetNewIDictionaryStringDouble();
...
var fbv = new SomeClass<string, string>
    (startingProbabilities: (s => startingProbabilitiesDict[s]), 
     transitionProbabilities: ((sOut, sIn) => transitionProbabilitiesDict[sOut][sIn]), 
     emissionProbabilities: ((s, o) => emissionProbabilitiesDict[s][o]));
```

where the `SomeClass` default constructor is

```
public class SomeClass<O, S> : IObserver<Tuple<O, IEnumerable<S>>>
{       
    ...
    public SomeClass(
        Func<S, double> startingProbabilities,
        Func<S, S, double> transitionProbabilities,
        Func<S, O, double> emissionProbabilities)
    {
        Contract.Requires(startingProbabilities != null);
        Contract.Requires(transitionProbabilities != null);
        Contract.Requires(emissionProbabilities != null);

        StartingProbabilities = startingProbabilities;
        TransitionProbabilities = transitionProbabilities;
        EmissionProbabilities = emissionProbabilities;
    }
    ...
}
```

I am confused over this notation:

```
startingProbabilities: (s => startingProbabilitiesDict[s])
```

It seems as thought the `startingProbabilities:` is specifying the fisrt parameter of the constructor, but **why is the colon necessary and what is this notation called?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called a [Named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

The name is optional, if you combine the usage with optional arguments it gets more interesting (simplified/dumb example below):

```
[Test]
public void NamedAndUnnamedTest()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("Only value1 was supplied", DummyMethod(value1: 1));
    Assert.AreEqual("Only value1 was supplied", DummyMethod(1));
    Assert.AreEqual("Only value2 was supplied", DummyMethod(value2: 1));
    Assert.AreEqual("Both arguments were supplied", DummyMethod(1, 2));
}

private string DummyMethod(int value1 = 0, int value2 = 0)
{
    if (value1 != 0 && value2 != 0)
        return "Both arguments were supplied";
    if (value1 == 0)
        return "Only value2 was supplied";
    return "Only value1 was supplied";
}
```